# Python visualization using for loop

Tags: python, visualization

I have dataframe df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, and df7.

I am trying to create a scatter plot of 7 subplots using a for loop.

The scatter plot code is written below. For every iteration, I want to change all the df to df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, and df7.

```
plt.scatter(np.log10(df.variable), mod1.predict(df), label='Modeled')
plt.scatter(np.log10(df.variable), df[dependent], label='Actual')
plt.title('Actual Frequency vs Modeled')
```

Any suggestions on how to write this for loop?

Comment: I know it's bad form, but I honestly do not believe you have googled "how do I write a for loop in Python" yet.

Comment: This is a fairly easy google task. You can search for "python for loops".

Answer (score 1):

## The solution shouldn't involve `exec`. Here you go:

```py
figure, axes = plt.subplots(1, 8)  # 1 row, 8 cols

for i, df in enumerate([df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7]):
    plt.scatter(np.log10(df.variable), mod1.predict(df), label='Modeled', ax=axes[i])
    plt.scatter(np.log10(df.variable), df[dependent], label='Actual', ax=axes[i])

plt.title('Actual Frequency vs Modeled')
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following code snippet works.

```
for i in range(1,8):
    exec("df = df{}".format(i))
    plt.scatter(np.log10(df.variable), mod1.predict(df), label='Modeled')
    plt.scatter(np.log10(df.variable), df[dependent], label='Actual')
    plt.title('Actual Frequency vs Modeled')
```

Updated:

```
fig = plt.figure()
rows = 4
columns = 2

for i in range(1,8):
    exec("df = df{}".format(i))
    plt.subplot(rows, columns, i)
    plt.scatter(np.log10(df.variable), mod1.predict(df), label='Modeled')
    plt.scatter(np.log10(df.variable), df[dependent], label='Actual')
    plt.title('Actual Frequency vs Modeled')
plt.show()
```

P.S.: I think it should work. I haven't tested it on my environment.

Comment: Thank you, but is there anyway to show 7 plots separately?  like 7 subplots